# Display error for a text field when not meet the pattern requirement (HTML5)

Tags: css, html

I am new to html5 coding, so would someone kindly help me with my problem.

I am doing a school work where I need to specify the pattern on the text field in html5 to only accept **6 digits and 1 letter** ONLY (eg. 123456A).

I managed to get what I want but, the problem is that how to display the error **if the user types wrongly?**

This school assignment of mine must be done with only html5 and css. No Javascript whatsoever. Thanks for your expertise.

So far here's what I've done.

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
        Enter Adm No: 
     <input type="text" name="admNo"  pattern="[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{1}"
    title="6 digits and 1 letter" required/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: By only using html and css you can't achieve that warning at value entering. You need some javascript  for that.

Comment: It does already...in Chrome - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GrJRwy

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Comment: Thank for your wonderful comment, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, but it won't display any message, just a red border.

You can eventually try to insert a text as long as pattern do not match and even hide the submit input.

example with the pseudo class `:invalid` and an extra tag to allow text to be inserted while pattern required doesn't match.

```css
/* possible style */

input:invalid {
  color: red;
  /* turn to red as long as pattern do not match */
}
input:invalid+b:before {
  content: 'Invalid Number';/* add text untill patterns matches */
}
input:invalid+b+[type="submit"] {
  display: none; /* hide input submit untill pattern matches */
}
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
  Enter Adm No:
  <input type="text" name="admNo" pattern="[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{1}" title="6 digits and 1 letter" required/>
  <b><!-- can be used to insert text via pseudo element where input do not--></b>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it really didn't come to mind of using this method until you brought it up. You are really helpful. Great tips!!

Comment: I came up with something very similar. Probably best to avoid promoting the use of inserting text content from within the CSS though, when it could just be part of the HTML as content or via an attribute of some sort.

Comment: @seemly why should an error message should be hard coded at all time in the dom when it used to be a typical javascript's job ?

Comment: Technically you have still hard coded it, just not in the place another developer would expect to find it.

Comment: @seemly CSS is style and not part of the DOM, but you 're right, at one point things needs to be coded and written done to be executed or read ;) ... else they do not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do anything regarding only displaying the alert if the field is invalid, because technically the field is invalid until it meets the validation pattern. But you could do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld5fuz75/2/

```css
input ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
input:invalid ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Adm No:
  <input type="text" name="admNo" pattern="[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{1}" title="6 digits and 1 letter" required />
  <input type="submit" />

  <span class="alert">Form is invalid</span>
</form>
```